# What is indeed the "first known use"?

Tags: etymology

Why, after a quick lookup at the Google online library, allowing the browsing of the content of available books, can I inevitably find instances prior to the first known use in the dictionary of certain words?

Comment: Mostly it'll be because the dates in google books aren't very reliable - witness all these instances of [Internet before 1950](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=internet&year_start=1700&year_end=1950&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: I must confess: It was me who used my time machine, and wrote a book about Internet before 1750.

Comment: The OED, which has the best quality of "first known use" AFAIK, was populated by readers sending in slips of paper with early quotations they could find (plus its editors doing their best). This crowd-sourcing was the best they could do at the time. Take a look at [Murray and the OED](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=James_Murray_(lexicographer)&oldid=441504319#Murray_and_the_OED) and [OED#History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OED#History), or the book [The Meaning of Everything: The Story of the Oxford English Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Everything).

Comment: I've also read great reviews of *[The Surgeon of Crowthorne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Surgeon_of_Crowthorne)* (titled *The Professor and the Madman: A Tale of Murder, Insanity, and the Making of the Oxford English Dictionary* in North America), a book about one of the most prolific contributors. (E.g. NYT: *[The Strange Case of the Madman With a Quotation for Every Word](http://www.nytimes.com/1998/09/07/books/the-strange-case-of-the-madman-with-a-quotation-for-every-word.html&pagewanted=all)*) As Hugo says, if you find earlier quotes that aren't (say) OCR errors, please do contribute.

Comment: @Lrc007 Please will you share some of these words you've found with earlier first known use? Thanks!

Comment: @Hugo As the word "caprice", of which I've found a great bulk of antecedents before 1600, and the earliest ones pointing to 1439. One good example of the antecedents of this word can be cited from "An open letter to the Christian nobility of the German nation":...,and besides he is at all times to be dependent upon the caprice of the pope and his followers,...

Comment: That's indeed a good example. [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=caprice&allowed_in_frame=0) says *caprice* is from 1660s. Martin Luther's open letter was  originally written in German in 1520, but you found *caprice* in the [20th century English translation](http://books.google.com/books?id=zYUXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA154&dq=%22caprice%22+%22open+letter%22&hl=en&ei=9KOuTqDTI6Xf4QT1iJnhDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=caprice&f=false) by C.M. Jacobs (1875-1938).

Comment: @Hugo I mistook the translation to my neglect. Translations precluded, there is litte usage of this word in English and is not verifiable. 16c. French sources are available all but as described in entries from **Etymonline**. Other words I picked randomly like "backdrop", "soloist" and so on, though several trivial antecedents one or two year prior in time, can hardly mar the credibility of these etymology study. And in this case, I may believe that most of the origin/date can be trusted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the fist known use of a word is exactly that: the first **known** use. If and when they find an antecedent, they will usually update the dictionary entry.

There's no way for them to search every single book and document ever published, and not every publication still exists. However, more documents are being computerised and indexed so this makes it easier to find antecedents.

The OED are very happy to receive antedatings for inclusion in future editions, as well as new meanings. Check their [FAQ](http://www.oed.com/public/faqs#contribute) to find out how to contribute.

Comment: It appears that They haven't been very efficient.

Comment: The editors of the OED have strict criteria for including words and citations.

Comment: "They haven't been very efficient." -- This assessment only seems plausible in our current world.  Most of the work in finding first usages was done long before computers and digital texts, much less the internet making some of them available to casual users.

Comment: +1 for making me look up and learn another word, I'll let you guess which one. ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer *Antecedent/antedate*? And I challenge the OP to antedate the late 14c. *antecedent* or find an antecedent of *antedate* prior to the 1580s :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. And the answer is pretty simple: the dictionary is *huge* and it takes a while to do the research to update it. Therefore, when you're searching right now with Google Books, sometimes you're competing with research that was done decades ago by people who didn't have access to the internet.

The internet, specifically things like Google Books and other databases that have searchable text of old documents, makes etymological research so much easier. And it's still getting better as OCR improves and more stuff is scanned into databases.

In the online OED you might see something like this:

> [image: Red text from OED that says: "This entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1915)."]

This is your signal that the page is out-of-date.

(Note: The one thing that needs to be said about Google Books is that it doesn't always get the year right. Be sure to check the front page of the book to see what date is printed there before getting your hopes up.)